# How to properly use the .animate() function -- top

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

Is this the proper way to use the .animate(top) function?

Positive number (animate down)--

```
    $("div#container div#history-menu").animate({top:'180px'}, 600);
```

Negative number (animate up)--

```
    $("div#container div#history-menu").animate({top:'-180px'}, 600);
```

Because I'm getting a java error in my error console that says:

"error in parsing value for property 'top'.  Declaration Dropped."

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: '180px' and '-180px' should be valid values for animate (see http://api.jquery.com/animate/#entry-examples). Can you post the HTML / CSS / surrounding JS?

Comment: @Jeffrey -- My problem is that I have multiple statements like that in my .js file and can't pinpoint where the actual error is located.  But all my animate statements look exactly like the ones I posted so I figured that would be my starting point....not sure what to do now.

Comment: Do the error messages you are getting have a line number attached? Can you try commenting out code to narrow it down? Perhaps build a simplified demo page that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the values from ({top: '-180px'}, 600) to ({top: '-=180'}, 600) or ({top:'+=180'},600) seems to eliminate my problem.